# Testing an app on a jailbroken iDevice (WITH CERTIFICATE)

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to jailbreak my iDevice and to test my app (which uses Game Center- thus needs sandboxed environment) on the jailbroken device. Now I know that jailbreaking is all about getting out of the sandbox- In that case, What should I do?

Thanks!

Note: I have a legal certificate from Apple

EDIT:
I'm a registered Apple developer, I just wanna test my app on my jailbroken device- I want to know if I even can to do this, if not I'll just bother myself for nothing because I'll need to restore...

Comment: Well, to jailbreak your iPhone, go to http://evasi0n.com...

Comment: No no no- I know how to jailbreak- I'm developing an app for iOS (for the OFFICIAL App Store), and I want to test in on my jailbroken iOS device- I want to check if it works

Comment: Apart from the obvious question (why wouldn't it work?): then why don't you just go ahead and install the app on a jailbroken device?

Comment: H2CO3 is right - there should not be any issues. They say certain things working under sandbox do not work properly when jailbroken, but that's not true. Installing is very small step that is not irrevokable. Just give it a try.

Comment: If you have a jailbroken phone, you can choose to install your app inside, or outside of the sandbox.  If you use the *normal* Build and Run process with Xcode, the app will be installed, sandboxed, in `/var/mobile/Applications/*` and will still be limited to normal sandbox rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Apps, such as those from the app store, still follow the rules laid down by Apple. I've seen people have issues with Game Center after jailbreaking their devices but they weren't developers/developing anything and the issues were usually resolved.

Anyway, I have a jailbroken device that I use to test Apps I've made. I'm a registered developer and I've experienced no issues with my phone being jailbroken.